# How to print php arrays in Html?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a php file and do all  the processing to save information in arrays.Then i write Html to represent the data from  the Arrays.I want each row of the table to have the i-element of the arrays but until now i get only the last row,so i suppose my for loop is not working.This is the code i have

```
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>XML file Data</h2>

<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Lesson Title</th>
        <th>ClassRoom</th>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Professor</th>


    </tr>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($lessonTitleArray); $i++) : ?>



        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $lessonTitleArray[$i]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $classRoomArray[$i]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $DayArray[$i]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $TimeArray[$i]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $professorArray[$i]; ?></td>


        </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You expect us to guess how `$lessonTitleArray` is filled with values?

Comment: `$lessonTitleArray` seems to have 2 values

Comment: try using brackets instead of `:` and `endfor;`... also try to use `print_r($array)` and post what that print on your page

Comment: @u_mulder the Arrays are filled with data.the code is here https://pastebin.com/qft8sKDS

Comment: The colon and endfor make the presentation much more readable and have no effect on the logic. However, an echo or print will not display an array. A quick and dirty way would be `<td><pre><?= print_r($lessonTitleArray[$i],true) ?></pre></td>`.  (Note the short echo tag is merely a shorthand way of writing the verbose `<?php echo`)  (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: @TimMorton i tested your code and i am geting the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code, and input my values in arrays. All great print in table

[image]

Please, check you arrays with `var_dump()` function

Comment: array (size=1)
    0 => string 'Artificial Intelligence' (length=23)

    array (size=1) 
     0 => string 'Constraint Satisfaction Problems' (length=32)

    array (size=1)
    0 => string 'Knowledge Representation in Web' (length=31)

    array (size=1)
    0 => string 'Artificial Intelligence' (length=23)

    array (size=1)
    0 => string 'AI Programming' (length=14)

    array (size=1)
    0 => string 'Introduction to Procedural Programming' (length=38)

   @Андрій Унгурян i am getting this result

Comment: And you get the result in one row, because of min size your arrays equal 1. Your code works great.